# Repository problems

Tags: apt, repository

I have a fairly longstanding repository error that won't let me install software, among other things.  I have avoided dealing with it, as I do not fully understand how the repository/verification system works.
When I sudo apt-get update, at the end of the list, I get (subbed dot for dot to allow me to post with my reputation)

```
Ign httpcol//repo.steampowereddotcom precise/steam Translation-en                  
Ign httpcol//ppa.launchpaddotnet trusty InRelease                                  
Ign httpcol//ppa.launchpaddotnet trusty InRelease                                  
Ign httpcol//ppa.launchpaddotnet trusty InRelease                                  
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg [316 B]                     
97% [1 Packages bzip2 0 B] [InRelease gpgv 89.8 kB] [10 Packages 3,023 kB/5,859Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/launchpad.net_%7eeugenesan_+archiIgn httpscol//launchpaddotnet trusty InRelease                                     ature failed
E: GPG error: https//launchpad.net trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

accordingly I found a troubleshooting post that stated that I should run:

```
sudo echo "deb http//archive.ubuntudotcom/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update
```

Tried that, didn't work.

```
$ wget -O - -S httpcol//extras.ubuntudotcom/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
```

and I did, but it returned what it indicated was proper:

```
--2014-11-03 12:25:56--  httpcol//extrasdotubuntudotcom/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
Resolving extrasdotubuntudotcom (extrasdotubuntudotcom)... 91.189.92.152
Connecting to extrasdotubuntu.com (extrasdotubuntudotcom)|91.189.92.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 17:25:59 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 310
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2014-11-03 12:25:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

This part looks weird to me:

```
7% [1 Packages bzip2 0 B] [InRelease gpgv 89.8 kB] [10 Packages 3,023 kB/5,859Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/launchpaddotnet_%7eeugenesan_+archiIgn httpscol//launchpaddotnet trusty InRelease                                     ature failed<<
```

but I don't know what to do about it. Anyone have a clue as to what this problem is or how to resolve it?  Help, please!?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I fixed it.  I had at least two problems, one was a hash-sum mismatch, another a missing key.  I couldn't find those problems until I disabled (and removed) a ppa.  Now my updates are clean.